# redux, normalizr, access store mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

If I have a data object like below

```
 {
   items: [
     {id: 1, selected: false},
     {id: 2, selected: false}
   ]
 }
```

Running this through the normalizr would get me something like

```
{
  entities: {
    1: {selected: false},
    2: {selected: false}
  },
  result: {
    items: [1, 2]
  }
}
```

Typically I would have an Items component that maps the state to props like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state.result;
};
```

The problem I have is on the Items component, I would have a save button that needs to send the state of the store to the server.

I haven't seem to be able to find a good way to access the store to denormalize the data before sending it to the server.

1) I prefer not to include the Entities in MapStateToProps because there is no need for the items component to know about it.

2) MergeProps also seems suboptimal due to performance issues.

Right now I'm accessing the store directly by simply importing the store and accessing it in my dispatch methods which seems to work, but that breaks the separation of concern, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the description of your problem, I believe you send the store's data by a method inside Save button component, or another React component. If you do that, you must expose the sending data to that component no matter what.

An alternative solution is to handle the API call by a middleware. Libraries such as redux-saga or redux-thunk can handle your case neatly. They are designed to handle async flows, and provide access to the store.

Comment: You are correct, I do not want to expose the data to that Items component though because I don’t want it re-rendered every time one of the item changes. I have heard of redux thunk but have not tried yet, is that any different from how I am simply importing the store now?

Comment: Please see the articles listed in the [Learning Resources#Basic Side Effects](https://redux.js.org/introduction/learningresources#side-effects-basics) section of the Redux docs for info on thunks.

Comment: Above comment is on point. Basically, in your case, those libraries help you to move API-related logic to redux's middleware, and separate concern of third-party data from React layer. Redux has good documentation and [example](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#example-using-thunk-middleware-for-async-actions), so check them out first.